# SerialPort check CTS

Tags: c#, winapi, serial-port, interop

How to check `CTS` line value of opened `SerialPort`? Idea is to set this value from device on other side while using 3-wire serial interface without handshaking.

Here is some code to start discussion (adapted [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363424(v=vs.85).aspx) example):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCommMask(IntPtr hFile, uint dwEvtMask);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool WaitCommEvent(IntPtr hFile, out uint lpEvtMask, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

SerialPort _port = null;
bool _exit;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _port = new SerialPort("COM2");
    _port.Open();

    // getting handle is tricky
    var handle = ((SafeFileHandle)_port.BaseStream.GetType().GetField("_handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(_port.BaseStream)).DangerousGetHandle();

    // set mask to listen to change of CTS signal
    if (!SetCommMask(handle, 0x0008)) // EV_CTS
        throw ...

    // start listener
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!_exit)
        {
            uint mask = 0;
            if (WaitCommEvent(handle, out mask, IntPtr.Zero))
                if ((mask & 0x0008) != 0)
                    Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("smth happenz"));
        });
        _port.Close();
    }
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _exit = true;
}
```

This code can tell me if there is a **change** of signal on `CTS` line, but can't figure out how to get actual **value** (is it high or low?).

Apart from that there are strange issues. `WaitCommEvent` returns `false` immediately (with `Marshal.GetLastError() = 0`) unless `CTS` is set to *opposite to what it was when com-port was opened*. Moreover, I see `MessageBox` for values which are *equal to what it was when com-port was opened*. This is really weird, because I can't figure out a value by using this approach.

Another thing is what `WaitCommEvent` *blocks*. I can close form and application terminates without visible (yet?) issues, but I'd really enjoy having non-blocking polling here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`GetCommModemStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363258(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve status of CTS.

You can use `WaitCommEvent` in non-blocking mode with overlapped IO. That is, opening the port as overlapped and providing the 3rd parameter of `WaitCommEvent`.

Comment: Exactly function I was looking for. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

A 3-wire serial interface does not include the CTS signal, so you cannot use it.

As for reading the value of CTS, the documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx you want to look at `GetCommMask()` and `GetCommModemStatus()`.

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#3-wire_and_5-wire_RS-232) *"A minimal "3-wire" RS-232 connection consisting only of transmit data, receive data, and ground, is commonly used when the full facilities of RS-232 are not required.*"  --I am sorry, but here on stackoverflow the culture is to answer what the OP *asks*, not what the OP *means*.

Comment: I'll check if interface works or not when I manually control `CTS` while having `Handshake = none` tomorrow. Maybe you are right and I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Sinatr Okay, let me know, out of curiosity.  Good luck!